# FB.event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(href, widget) {... doesn't work

Tags: facebook, event-handling, facebook-like

today I tried to insert an event-trigger for unliking a facebook-fanpage via

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(href, widget) {
    top.location.href = '<?= $config['facebook_tab_url'] ?>';
});
```

because I use a layer when a user doesn't like a page. Under the layer there is only a screenshot of the app so deleting the layer via firebug or other tools won't work.

i check the like-status via PHP and the code

```
$signed_request = $_POST['signed_request'];
$parsed_signed_request = parse_signed_request($signed_request, $config['app_secret']);

$liked = isset($parsed_signed_request['page']['liked']) && $parsed_signed_request['page']['liked'] == 1;
$nolikestatus = !isset($parsed_signed_request['page']['liked']);
```

So I can differ the HTML-content via

```
<?php if ($liked || $nolikestatus): ?>
    HTML-CONTENT
<?php else: ?>
    HTML-CONTENT with screenshot and Layer.
<? endif; ?>
```

That's why I have to redirect to the app's start-page when the user likes the page via

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    top.location.href = '<?= $config['facebook_tab_url'] ?>';
});
```

which is working, but the unlike-event won't trigger and I don't know why! Everywhere it says "edge.remove" is the way to go, but as far as I can tell it doesnt't work!

Hope you understand my problem and know any solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `edge.remove` will work with the [Like button *plugin*](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) **only**. Not with the built-in Facebook Page Like button.